# Own RSI calculation divers from Altcoin Tradingview RSI ... Does anyone know why?

Tags: python, pine-script

I've tried several ways to get the same RSI like Tradingview. The funny thing is, that my own calculated RSI matches e.g. the Bitcoin related RSI's perfectly. But when i try to calculate the RSI for altcoins, it's different. I have tried different EMA/RMAs, Excel recreation and of course python. Even: XRSIs (eg: RSI = 0,6 RSI-XRP + 0,4 RSI-BTC), but never got the same result.

Does anyone know how Tradingview is calculating the AltCoin RSIs?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,
Domi

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of the RSI should be the same for any kind of data in Tradingview. In Pinescript the RSI can be calculated from scratch as follows:

```
pine_rsi(x, y) => 
    u = max(x - x[1], 0) // upward change
    d = max(x[1] - x, 0) // downward change
    rs = rma(u, y) / rma(d, y)
    res = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
    res
```

If the results differ it might be due to rounding errors, another cause might the use of data different from the one provided by Tradingview.

Answer (score 1):

They are using a smoothed RSI formula. I checked it against the one year chart which uses daily bars.

```
    import yfinance as yf
    import talib as ta

    #get data
    ticker = yf.Ticker("BTC-USD")
    period = '10y' 
    interval = '1d' 
    data = ticker.history(interval=interval, period= period)
    df = data .reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns={"index": "Date"})
    df['RSI_Ta'] = ta.RSI(df['Close'], timeperiod=14)
    df
```

It is the same as Yahoo data somehow. Which is strange because I buy and sell as a market maker for higher and lower prices most every day.